# Looking for feedback on a Motor Control design 2x SPDT with IPT004N03L

Tags: mosfet-driver, powermosfet

I'm designing a reversing DC motor board, with a power MOSFET to provide slow start/stop capability. I'm using 2 SPDT high power relays to control the motor direction, with a IPT004N03L power MOSFET to provide the slow start mechanism.

- Power Input: 10-15V DC
- PWM Frequency: 1kHz
- Current: 40A Max
- Duty Cycle: 2-3 minutes, twice a day

I want to make sure the MOSFET driver is good enough to support this beast of a MOSFET, but haven't dealt with MOSFETs at this power level before.

Bottom layer large traces are exposed and flooded with solder. Thermal pad to a large aluminum case conducts heat away from the board.

I tried this before with a UCC27517 MOSFET driver, but the driver kept burning up. I have switched to the COS4424SR with a larger voltage range and added more diodes to help absorb voltage spikes.

Schematic:
[image: schematic]

MOSFET Layout:
[image: mosfet]